# Whitespace in csv output - Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I keep having issues with a clean csv output.

Here is the Program:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_108-tot-127-cm-43-tot-50-,98952,501090.html?langId=-17')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

outfile = open("./tv_test1.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="category"]/ul[2]/li')
writer.writerow(["Product Name", "Price"])

for row in rows:
    price = row.xpath('div/aside[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text()')
    product_ref = row.xpath('div/div/h2/a/text()')
    writer.writerow([product_ref,price])

outfile.close()
```

Current Output:

```
['\r\n\t\t\t\t\tTV SAMSUNG UE48JU6640UXXN 48" LCD FULL LED Smart Ultra HD Curved\r\n\t\t\t\t'],"['999,-']"
```

Required output:

```
TV SAMSUNG UE48JU6640UXXN 48" LCD FULL LED Smart Ultra HD Curve,999,-
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

page =
requests.get('http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_108-tot-127-cm-43-tot-50-,98952,501090.html?langId=-17')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

outfile = open("./tv_test1.csv", "wb") writer = csv.writer(outfile)

rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="category"]/ul[2]/li')
writer.writerow(["Product Name", "Price"])

for row in rows:
    price = row.xpath('normalize-space(div/aside[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text())')
    product_ref = row.xpath('normalize-space(div/div/h2/a/text())')
    writer.writerow([product_ref,price])

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove `\n` , `\r` and `\t` before writing the data inside the csv file:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_108-tot-127-cm-43-tot-50-,98952,501090.html?langId=-17')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

outfile = open("./tv_test1.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

rows = tree.xpath('//*[@id="category"]/ul[2]/li')
writer.writerow(["Product Name", "Price"])

for row in rows:
    price = row.xpath('div/aside[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text()')
    for i in range(len(price)):
        price[i]= price[i].replace("\n","")
        price[i]= price[i].replace("\t","")
        price[i]= price[i].replace("\r","")

    product_ref = row.xpath('div/div/h2/a/text()')
    for i in range(len(product_ref)):
        product_ref[i]= product_ref[i].replace("\n","")
        product_ref[i]= product_ref[i].replace("\t","")
        product_ref[i]= product_ref[i].replace("\r","")
    if len(product_ref) and len(price):
        writer.writerow([product_ref,price])

outfile.close()
```

And you will have:

[image]

*Note that I also checked length of `price` and `product_ref` before storing them in file.*

Comment: `strip()` would also work since those characters are on the ends

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, but using this methodology the inner characters can be removed too.